# Dynamic table and model generate in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I want to create some database tables and `models.Model` on api call in django. I created on demand Model 

`model = type(str(project_slug + "_tbl_name"), (models.Model,), attrs)`

and I want to create table like this 

`db.create_table(table_name, fields)`

create_table was from [south](https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/databaseapi.html#db-create-table)
but south is not available in Django 1.11 what I am using

How can I generate Model and database tables programmatically?

Comment: you can look on [createmodel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#createmodel)

Comment: I already generated models. but cannot genrate db tables

Comment: did you read the docs? `create model in the **project history** and a corresponding table in the database to match it.`

Comment: done that but it has not created any table

Comment: because it is a migration operation. I dont know how to apply it programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/schema-editor/#create-model

example:

```
with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
   schema_editor.create_model(my_model)
```